# C++ Find string before text

Tags: c++, string

The given code gets all the text **after** a specific point in a string and works very well.

```
if(text.find("what ") != std::string::npos)
        {
            foundtext = text.substr(text.find("what ") + 5);
            cout << foundtext << endl;
        }
```

The next problem that I can't figure out even after searching, is to find the material **before** a specific point. Unfortunetely it wasn't as simple as turning the +5 into a -5. How could I fint the string that comes before "what "?

Comment: text.substring(0,positionof(what)) perhaps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to supply two arguments to `substr()`:

```
foundtext = text.substr(0, text.find("what "));
```

The first (`0`) is the starting position and the second is the length.

Comment: You should accept the answer if it solved your problem